# jQuery check if input id has a value

Tags: jquery, performance

I'm pretty new to jquery so this may be pretty simple. But I've got a simple snippet of code that looks for an ID of phone number and if it has a value do something.  But I can't seem to get it to work and there must be a more efficient way to do it than I am using.  Newbie so any help is greatly appreciated.

```
if ($(this).attr("id") == "phoneNumber") {
    if ($(this).val().length == 0) {
        alert(placeholderText + " check phone number");
        valid = false;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will select the phoneNumber element from the DOM and check the value:

```
if($("#phoneNumber").val().length == 0){
   alert(placeholderText + " check phone number");
   valid = false;
   return false;
}
```

What you have (presumably called in an event handler) will check to see if the element that is processing the event has `id="phoneNumber"` and, if so, checks the value.

Answer (score 1):

First, you can access the element like this:

```
$('#phoneNumber')
```

To check if the element exists, you can do something like this:

```
if($('#phoneNumber').length)
{

}
```

To have a listener check the field on an event, like on blur, you can do this:

```
$('#phoneNumber').on('blur', function(){
    if($(this).val() == "")
    {
        alert("Please enter a phone number");
    }
});
```

If you update your question with exactly what you want to do we may be able to help write it out.

Answer (score 0):

If the element `id` attribute is `phoneNumber` you will need to select that element.

```
$('#phoneNumber').val()
```

If the element is not an `<input>`, but a block level element like a `<div>` you should use `.text()`

```
$('#phoneNumber').text().trim();
```

Also in it's current state, if the `$('#phoneNumber')` element HAS a `val()` with a length greater than 0, nothing will be returned.

Since you set `valid` to false, you should return `valid outside of your`if/else` i.e.:

```
var $phoneNumber = $('#phoneNumber');
var $phoneNumberVal = $phoneNumber.val().trim(); //make sure to trim for whitespace
var valid;
if($phoneNumberVal.length === 0){
    valid = false;
} else if ($phoneNumberVal.length > 0) {
    valid = true;
}
return valid;
```